# Redirecting dynamic(variable) subdomain to a controller using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a user page url of the form `user1.mydomain.com` , and I need it to redirect to `http://mydomain.com/index.php/users/index/user1` .

In my .htaccess file, I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/index.php/users/index/$1 [L]
```

I am getting "this webpage is not available" from google chrome, at least not a server error.

What am I doing wrong? Also, in the rewriterule pattern, how does it know that $1 refers to the subdomain and not the full url? Is it because I have `%{HTTP_HOST}` in my rewritecond ?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` captures into `%1` rather than `$1`.  That might be all you need here - everything else looks correct.

Comment: But do you need to append the URI onto it like `http://user1.example.com/path` --> `http://example.com/index.php/users/index/user1/path`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski For now I don't need to append anything, i just want the subdomain to convert to the users page with no parameters

Comment: Also, does apache or mod_rewrite keep a log where I can check where it redirected to, maybe I can understand what went wrong from that.

Comment: You have to manually enable `RewriteLog`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog and set a `RewriteLogLevel` to determine how much detail you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captured variables from `RewriteCond` are denoted as `%1`, `%2` etc...

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.com/index.php/users/index/%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Still the same result (this webpage is not available) with your rules, can you suggest anything else? thanks.

Comment: Rule is correct but your setup might be different than expected. Is DocumentRoot for `user1.mydomain.com` same as `mydomain.com`?

Comment: Also what is location of above .htaccess? What happens when you enter `http://user1.mydomain.com/` with above rule?

Comment: I don't think I have set up the document root for subdomains. How would I do that given that user1 is variable ?

Comment: Location of .htaccess is at DocumentRoot for mydomain.com
Can you please define what a working sub-domain is?
I do not plan to to activate any specific subdomains, I just need the url to look personalized (user1.mydomain.com).

Comment: When you enter `http://user1.mydomain.com` does it open any page at present (without any rewrite rule)

Comment: Same "This webpage does not exist".

Comment: Well that means that your sub domain isn't even valid.

Comment: Makes sense, how can I validate it? Also, it is not one subdomain, the name will depend on the user.
Should I add a VirtualHost directive in my apache config file with something like this: <VirtualHost *.mydomain.com:80> ,and put the document root inside?
 Can you please clarify more?

Comment: I don't have lot of server admin knowledge but I think `user1.mydomain.com` and `user2.mydomain.com` etc need to be separate `VirtualHost` entries.

Comment: Okay, I will check further. But this won't help me because I do not want to keep editing apache configs everytime I add a user. But Thanks for the rewrite script.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a wildcard DNS record to my A records, and now subdomains are working along with the rewriting. One more thing though, in the rewriterule, you specified R for redirect. I do not want it to redirect, so I removed the R, but this resulted in a server error, any ideas?

Comment: yes because while changing the domains in redirect name you need to use `R` flag (or enable mod_proxy and use `P` flag)